# For which values of $C\in \mathbb{R}$ does $f(x, C) = - f(y, C)$ have solutions $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have two differential equations:

\begin{equation}
x' = x(1-y)\\
y' = y(x-1)
\end{equation}

After some tricks, where you can use:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(x-1)}{x(1-y)} \rightarrow \int \frac{(1 - y)}{y} dy = \int \frac{(x-1)}{x}dx.
\end{equation}

This eventually leads to:
\begin{equation}
- f(y, c) = \log(y) - y + C = x - \log(x) + C = f(x, y)
\end{equation}

How can I determine for which values of $C$ the functions solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

$$
\ln y-y=x-\ln x+C
$$

Assuming $x > 0, y > 0$ we have

$$
ye^{-y}= e^C \frac{e^x}{x}
$$

or

$$
e^C = x y e^{-(x+y)}
$$

now $x y  e^{-(x+y)}$ has a maximum at $x = y = 1$ then

$$
0 < e^C \le \frac{1}{e^2}\Rightarrow -\infty < C\le -2
$$